# android contacts querying return the contact name as a number

Tags: android, android-contacts

Am trying to query the database and display contacts and all their phone numbers, a row for each phone number:

Activity file:

```
 private Cursor getContacts() {

    Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] fields = new String[] {
            Data._ID,
            Phone.NUMBER,
            Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Phone.LABEL,
            Phone.TYPE,
    };
    String sortOrder = Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
    return managedQuery(uri, fields, null, null, sortOrder);
 }
private void populateContactList() {
   Cursor cursor = getContacts(); 
   String[] fields = new String[] {
        Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Phone.NUMBER,
    };
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_details, cursor,
            fields, new int[] {R.id.contactNameText, R.id.contactNumberText });
    mContactList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I get all the info I need, but it also shows every contacts name twice (as if it were the phone number) in one of the rows:

[image: snapshot]

Does anyone know what am doing wrong? any help will be appreciated!

[Here are the XML files (although  don't think they are the source of the problem)]:

```
//contact_list.xml <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/contactList"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/> 
//contact_details.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <TextView android:text="@+id/contactNumber"
          android:id="@+id/contactNumberText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
          />
 <TextView android:text="@+id/contactName"
          android:id="@+id/contactNameText"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contactNumberText"
          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code instead your method

```
private Cursor getContacts() {

Uri uri = Data.CONTENT_URI;
String[] fields = new String[] {
        Data._ID,
        Phone.NUMBER,
        Data.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Phone.LABEL,
        Phone.TYPE,
};
String sortOrder = Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
return managedQuery(uri, fields, Data.MIMETYPE + "='" + Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE+"'", null, sortOrder);
```

}

Comment: by the way You should read this part of manual http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did read that part, but I didn't pay attention to this specific line, I thought it was necessary for querying a single user's profile only (-since that's the example that was given...)